# how to configure appdynamics for multiple server?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, monitoring, appdynamics

Hi I am fairly new to appdynamics and using it to configure my server for trial period, I have 3 tomcats, I followed the documentation I got to know that we need to put appagent and machineagent to through data back to controller, If I try to download appagent and machineagent jar file fromir their official site I always end up with the same version and which ever tomcat starts first I get data only for that machine
[image]
This is what I have used for tomcat `catalina.sh`'

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms4G -Xmx12G -Xss256k -XX:MaxPermSize=1G -javaagent:/opt/appdynamics/ver4.0.3.0/javaagent.jar=staging1_tomcat=staging1_jv -Dappdynamics.controller.hostName=10.4.6.214 -Dappdynamics.controller.port=8090 -Dappdynamics.agent.applicationName=staging -Dappdynamics.agent.tierName=staging_tomcat_group -Dappdynamics.agent.nodeName=staging1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I ask if your trial is beyond 15 days? According to their site the trial only includes monitoring for one agent beyond that time - that would explain why only your first agent delivers data. Other tools in that space, e.g: Dynatrace free trial - gives you a bit more time if that's what you need and also allow you to extend the free trial if you need more time

Answer (score 0):

You have gone beyond the 15 day pro trial and you are using the free product. If you want to buy the product you can get an extension on the trial, if you do not want to buy the product it will not trace across JVMs.